# Can I "stop" a TFS Build where the only check-in comes from the prior build?

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I would like to implement a sort of CI where I build my solution on every checkin.  There is one problem, however, and that is that my build scripts often will automatically update certain files that do not change the actual compiled assemblies.  Is there a way to stop the automatic build (or to not even start) if the only check-in that's triggering it is from one of these "content" files?

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 1):

You can add the ***NO_CI*** tag to the checkin comment for these changes and they wont trigger a build.  Bing it and you'll find lots of examples for how to use it.